# how to get MTLVertexAttributeDescriptorArray size value in Metal

Tags: metal

In OpenGL, You can retrieve the maximum supported number of vertex attributes with glGetIntegerv(GL_MAX_VERTEX_ATTRIBS, &n).

So, how to get the maximum supported number of vertex attributes per vertex descriptor in Metal in addition to query through [Metal-Feature-Set-Tables](https://developer.apple.com/metal/Metal-Feature-Set-Tables.pdf)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is currently no API for querying most Metal implementation limits. You should [determine which family/version your device supports](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metal/mtldevice/1433418-supportsfeatureset), and use the values from the table, or else choose a sensible default.

For all extant Metal implementations, the maximum number of vertex attributes per vertex descriptor is 31. If you need more than that, you can fetch additional data from buffer arguments based on the current instance and vertex ID.